# Undefined reference when a function is listed in a header file, but fine if I copy and paste code directly

Tags: c++, header-files

I am working on a large project in C++ that is proprietary, so I can't actually share the source code.  I have most of the code compiled, but there is one function, in a particular file, that is giving me quite a bit of trouble.

I've created a simple example that shows what the problem is.  We have:

**WTPSHORT.H**

```
#ifndef WTP_H
#define WTP_H 1

#define  VERSION  "Version 2.1"
#define  DATE     "Nov., 2001"

/* ANSI C header files */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0


/************  Data structures for Water Treatment Plant ***************/

struct Effluent {    /******  Data Packet for All Unit Processes *******/
                 /* Operating data:                                */
  double  DegK;      /*   Temperature                          (Deg K) */
  double  Flow;      /*   Average flow                           (MGD) */
  double  Peak;      /*   Max hourly flow                        (MDG) */
                 /* Unit process counters:                         */
  short   cl2cnt;    /*   Number of times chlorine added.              */
                 /* Measurable Water Quality Parameters:           */
  double  pH;        /*   [H+]=pow(10,-pH)                         (-) */

  /* More variable definitions go here */

  double beta_br;   /* Constant for chlorine to bromine reactivity ratio */
  double time_step; /* Time step (hrs) */

};                   /************  End of struct Effluent  ************/


                              /*****************************************/
struct ProcessTrain {         /* Control Structure for Process Train   */
  struct UnitProcess  *head;  /*   First UnitProcess in ProcessTrain   */
  struct UnitProcess  *null;  /*   Always NULL                         */
  struct UnitProcess  *tail;  /*   Last UnitProcess in ProcessTrain    */
  char       file_name[120];  /*   Full path and extension             */
  };                          /*****************************************/


struct UnitProcess {         /********** Treatment Process ***************/
  struct UnitProcess *next;  /* Double Linked list                       */
  struct UnitProcess *prev;  /*   "      "     "                         */
  short               type;  /* Defined unit process types               */
  short               pad;   /* Maintain 32 bit alinment of pointers     */
  union {                    /* Design and operating parameters:          */
    void                 *ptr;
    struct Influent      *influent;
    struct Mechdbp       *mechdbp;                   //FOR MECH MODEL
    struct Alum          *alum;
     struct Gac           *gac;
    struct Filter        *filter;
    struct Basin         *basin;
//  struct Membrane      *membrane;
    struct Mfuf          *mfuf;
    struct Nf            *nf;
    struct Iron          *iron;
    struct chemical      *chemical;
    struct clo2          *clo2;
    struct lime          *lime;
  /*struct WTP_effluent  *wtp_effluent;  No longer needed - WJS, 11/98 */
    struct Avg_tap       *avg_tap;
    struct End_of_system *end_of_system;
    } data;

  struct Effluent     eff;
  };

struct Influent {      /* Raw Water Data                          */
  double  pH;          /* (-)                                     */
  double  temp;        /* Average temperature (C)                 */
  double  low_temp;    /* Low temperature for disinfection (C)    */
  double  toc;         /* (mg/L)                                  */
  double  uv254;       /* (1/cm)                                  */
  double  bromide;     /* (mg/L)                                  */
  double  alkalinity;  /* (mg/L as CaCO3)                         */
  double  calcium;     /* Calcium Hardness (mg/L as CaCO3)        */
  double  hardness;    /* Total   Hardness (mg/L as CaCO3)        */
  double  nh3;         /* Ammonia (mg/L as N)                     */
  double  ntu;         /* Turbidity                               */
  double  crypto_req;  /* Crypto Log removal + Log Inact. required*/
  double  clo2_crypto_ct_mult; /* Multiplier */
  double  peak_flow;   /* Peak Hourly Flow for disinfection (MGD) */
  double  avg_flow;    /* Average Flow (MGD)                      */
  int     swflag;      /* TRUE=Surface Water; FALSE=Ground Water  */
//  char    *run_name;

};         

void s1_s2_est(struct UnitProcess *unit);              

/* define(s) for UnitProcess.type */
#define  VACANT                 0
#define  INFLUENT               1
#define  RAPID_MIX              2
#define  SLOW_MIX               3
#define  SETTLING_BASIN         4
#define  FILTER                 5
#define  BASIN                  6
#define  CONTACT_TANK           7
#define  CLEARWELL              8
#define  O3_CONTACTOR           9 
#define  GAC                    10
#define  MFUF_UP                11
#define  NF_UP                  12

#endif
```

And then there are two source files in the project:

**s1s2_est.c**

```
/* s1s2_est.c --  December, 2000*/
#include "WTPSHORT.H"

void s1_s2_est(struct UnitProcess *unit)
{
    double toc, uva, s1_0, s2h_0, s2star_0, s2t_0, s1_f, s2h_f, s2star_f, s2t_f, H; 

    struct Effluent *eff;

    eff = &unit->eff;

    /* Get these inputs */
    toc      = eff->TOC;
    uva      = eff->UV;
    s1_0     = eff->s1;
    s2h_0    = eff->s2h;
    s2star_0 = eff->s2_star;
    H        = pow(10.0, -eff->pH);


    s2t_0 = s2h_0 + s2star_0;

    s1_f    = s1_0;
    s2t_f   = s2t_0;
    s2star_f    = s2star_0;
    s2h_f   = s2h_0;

    if(eff->s1_s2_estflag == 'C')
      {
       /* Safety check */
       if (toc < 0.0) toc = 0.0;
       if (uva < 0.0) uva = 0.0;

       s1_f  = 5.05 * pow(toc, 0.57) * pow(uva, 0.54);
       s2t_f = 13.1 * pow(toc, 0.38) * pow(uva, 0.40);

       /* No increases in the S values allowed */
       if(s1_f  > s1_0 ) s1_f  = s1_0;
       if(s2t_f > s2t_0) s2t_f = s2t_0;

       /* Speciate S2 */
       s2h_f    = s2t_f * eff->k21r * H / (eff->k21f + eff->k21r * H);
       s2star_f = s2t_f * eff->k21f     / (eff->k21f + eff->k21r * H);
      }   

    if(eff->s1_s2_estflag != 'C' && unit->type == INFLUENT)
      {/* Speciate S2 in raw water*/  
       s2h_f    = s2t_f * eff->k21r * H / (eff->k21f + eff->k21r * H);
       s2star_f = s2t_f * eff->k21f     / (eff->k21f + eff->k21r * H);
      }

    /* Update Effluent data structure */
    eff->s1      = s1_f;
    eff->s2h     = s2h_f;
    eff->s2_star = s2star_f;

}/* End subroutine "s1_s2_est()"*/
```

and then

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "WTPSHORT.H"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    UnitProcess *myunit;
    s1_s2_est(myunit);
    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling and linking I see this error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j8 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile"
       "----------Building project:[ simple - Debug ]----------"
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory         'C:/Users/joka0958/Desktop/wtp/compiledwtp/simple'
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c      "C:/Users/joka0958/Desktop/wtp/compiledwtp/simple/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -c  "C:/Users/joka0958/Desktop/wtp/compiledwtp/simple/s1s2_est.c" -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/s1s2_est.c.o -I. -I.
C:/Users/joka0958/Desktop/wtp/compiledwtp/simple/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
C:/Users/joka0958/Desktop/wtp/compiledwtp/simple/main.cpp:7:22: warning: 'myunit' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     s1_s2_est(myunit);
                      ^
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -o ./Debug/simple @"simple.txt" -L.
./Debug/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
C:/Users/joka0958/Desktop/wtp/compiledwtp/simple/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `s1_s2_est(UnitProcess*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[1]:  [Debug/simple] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe:  [All] Error 2
simple.mk:78: recipe for target 'Debug/simple' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/joka0958/Desktop/wtp/compiledwtp/simple'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
2 errors, 1 warnings
```

So the question is: Why am I getting an undefined reference?

I realize this is one of those errors that probably masks another problem, but I have really exhausted all possibilities, in my mind, of what could be causing the problem.  Note that this is part of a larger project where many other functions compile and link properly.

By the way I am using Codelite with the MinGW compiler on Windows 10.

Comment: "the definition of the function was not in scope" This sounds like there is _another_ `s1_s2_est` function in your code somewhere.  Is the function in a namespace and the prototype in the header not?

Comment: You are paraphrasing the compiler error you are observing, and you are paraphrasing the contents of your various header and source files. This is insufficient information for an answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information.

Comment: Undefined reference is typically a linking problem, not a compiling problem. Do you have all of the appropriate libraries specified?

Comment: I'm not sure what I am allowed to repost from this code, my apologies. Are there any general problems that could be occurring? For example some thing in the function code itself? Dozens of other functions are compiling fine.

Comment: The only function that is called within the offending function is pow, which should be ok since there is an include statement for math.h already in WTP.H

Comment: Do you have multiple projects within your workspace? Is the s1_s2_est source file in one but another? Is the s1_s2_est function somehow inside a namespace in its source file?

Comment: It could be a simple as the signature of the prototype not matching the actual function definition.  Make sure that the prototype signature (return type, function name, parameter list) are exactly identical.

Comment: You should aim to reduce the code to the smallest possible example of the fault you are seeing.

Comment: What happens when you add the extern keyword to the beginning of the declaration for s1_s2_est in the header?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for all the consternation this question caused.  It turns out that there was C++-specific functions within this file, but because the file was named with a *.c, codelite defaulted to the C compiler to actually compile this particular source file.  Once I changed the filename, the code compiled successfully.  Thanks for all of your useful suggestions!